# Trigger button event when press enter key on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

```
function CaptureKeys (e,btn) {
  var c //= document.layers ? evt.which: document.all ? event.keyCode : evt.keyCode 
  if(window.event) { 
    c = e.keyCode; // IE
  } else if(e.which) {
    c = e.which; // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
  }
      if (c == 13) {
        //return /enter key
        if (btn=="go") {
            if (document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnGo")!=null) {
                document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnGo").focus();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            if (document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImgFilter') != null) {
            //__doPostBack('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImgFilter','');
            document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ImgFilter').focus();
            return true;
           }
       }
      return false;
     }
 }
```

This code is working on IE7 but not working on Mozilla Firefox. Please help me to raise button event when press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Somehow I don't really think this is a bit of code that really should be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code:

```
theButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if anyone is checking this thread anymore, but for future reference.

I had the same problem in FF and I got the answer here:

<s>http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=108382</s>

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnGo','');
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnGo").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

`window.event` should be `window.Event` !

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add the **UseSubmitBehavior="true"** attribute value to your button that should be fired on <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: This is specific to ASP.net